# How to mock and check that a function from a library in Jest framework?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I have a button with "Download" text on it defined in ReactJS code. Now, I want to write a unit test to check that this function is getting called when this button is clicked. I wrote a unit test but it is not working.

```
import * as FileSaver from "file-saver"
  it('File has to be saved when clicked on the "Download" button', () => {
    jest.mock('file-saver', ()=>({saveAs: jest.fn()}));
    fireEvent.click(component.getByText("Download"));
    expect(FileSaver.saveAs).toBeCalled();
  })
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: expect(received).toBeCalled()
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function anonymous]
```

pointing to `expect(FileSaver.saveAs).toBeCalled();` line.

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the `spyOn` method? https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: Yes, here, I'm testing a library function which is causing the issue, I guess

Comment: Based on the error, the problem is that `FileSaver.saveAs` is not a mock, but probably a real implementation, so your `jest.mock()` doesn't work as it should. My guess is to try and move `jest.mock('file-saver', ()=>({saveAs: jest.fn()}))` from body of the test to the top of the file, just right under imports, then it should work.

Comment: @Panczur That's perfect. It worked. I put it right under the imports and it has passed now. Can you write it as an answer and explaining why too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as I stated in the comment, you have to move `jest.mock('file-saver', ()=>({saveAs: jest.fn()}))` from the body of the test to the top of the file, just under the imports. The reason for it is actually answered in the documentation [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports), but to wrap it up:

In your test file you are using `import` statement which fires up at start, before any code has a chance to run. Then you try to mock `file-saver`, but it is already imported with real implementation, not mocked. If you instruct `jest` to mock module at top of the file it will automatically hoist `jest.mock` calls to the top of the module so your function `exportToExcel` will receive mocked `file-saver` instead of the real one.

But if you really want to mock `file-saver` in the body of the test for some strange reason you would need to mock `file-saver`, then include all modules in test which use `file-saver`, something like this:

```
it('File has to be saved when clicked on the Export button', () => {
    jest.mock('file-saver', ()=> ({ saveAs: jest.fn() }));
    const component = require('/path/to/tested/componetn/on/which/click/event/is/fired');
    const FileSaver = require('file-saver');

    fireEvent.click(component.getByText("Download"));

    expect(FileSaver.saveAs).toBeCalled();
})
```